# Is registration point relative to stage's scale on EaselJS?

Tags: canvas, easeljs

Let's say I have a stage of 4*4.

If I scale the stage to be it's double (`stage.scaleX/Y * 2`), and set the registration point to be the center of the the original sized stage (`x:2, y:2`) it actually has the same effect of setting the position of the stage to (`x: -4, y: -4`).

So the registration point is relative to the stage's scale but the position doesn’t?

Any further explanation about the registration point is appreciated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5F5Ak/19/

Comment: I recommend not scaling the stage, and instead putting content in a container. The stage can be scaled, but the result may not be what you expect, and it could cause issues with mouse interaction, since scaling the stage wasn't really and intended use.

Comment: Yes, I actually scale a container inside the stage. Thanks for the hint!